# STM32f4 discovery audio sampling above 16kHz not working

Tags: audio, stm32f4

I'm trying to use digital microphone (MP45DT02) on stm32f4 discovery and just forward data to audio DAC and amplifier (CS43L22).

The problem is that at sampling frequency higher than 16kHz thing doesn't work anymore. I'm still hearing microphone input, but mainly beeping/scratching is coming out of the DAC.

Since MP45DT02 outputs data in pdm encoding I'm using pdm filter library that comes pre-build with STM's firmware package to get audio in PCM format. I'm using it as is described in document [AN3998 - PDM audio software decoding on STM32 microcontrollers](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00040808.pdf).

My program works as follows: when data is available from microphone, interrupt collects the samples, converts them to PCM (this is just like in example provided by ST) and adds them to queve. In main loop I write samples to the DAC if queve is not empty.

I compiled with gcc arm embedded 4.7, uC's frequnecy is 168MHz.

What I also tried, but result is the same:

- writing to the dac with interrupt (not in main loop)
- not using interrupts at all, firstly recording one second of audio and then playing it:

  while(true){
      record 1s of audio;
      play 1s of audio;
  }
- using another stm32f4 discovery board
- build everything with KEIL MDK.
- changing core frequency
- using DMA

Playing some 48kHz sound from flash works fine, so DAC is OK I guess.

Here is the code for microphone:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_spi.h"
#include "pdm_filter.h"
#include "queve.h"

//sampling frequency
#define FS 16000

//PDM decimation factor
#define DECIMATION 64

//i2s clock is clock for mic
//clock for mic is calculated as Fs*decimation_factor
//so we have to divide with 32 (frame_length*num_channels)
//to get i2s sampling freq
#define I2S_FS ((FS*DECIMATION)/(16*2))

//uint16_t array length for filter input buffer
#define MIC_IN_BUF_SIZE ((((FS/1000)*DECIMATION)/8)/2)


//uint16_t array length for filter output buffer
#define MIC_OUT_BUF_SIZE (FS/1000)

static PDMFilter_InitStruct pdm_filter;
static uint16_t mic_in_buf[MIC_IN_BUF_SIZE];
static uint16_t mic_out_buf[MIC_OUT_BUF_SIZE];
static uint32_t mic_buf_index;

void mp45dt02_init(void){
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_CRC, ENABLE);
    pdm_filter.LP_HZ=8000;
    pdm_filter.HP_HZ=10;
    pdm_filter.Fs=FS;
    pdm_filter.Out_MicChannels=1;
    pdm_filter.In_MicChannels=1;
    PDM_Filter_Init(&pdm_filter);

    //MP45DT02 CLK-PB10
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_10;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_SPI2);

    //MP45DT02 DOUT-PC3
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_3;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource3, GPIO_AF_SPI2);

    NVIC_InitTypeDef nvic;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannel = SPI2_IRQn;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&nvic);

    //I2S2 config
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI2, ENABLE);
    I2S_InitTypeDef i2s;
    i2s.I2S_AudioFreq=I2S_FS;
    i2s.I2S_Standard=I2S_Standard_LSB;
    i2s.I2S_DataFormat=I2S_DataFormat_16b;
    i2s.I2S_CPOL=I2S_CPOL_High;
    i2s.I2S_Mode=I2S_Mode_MasterRx;
    i2s.I2S_MCLKOutput=I2S_MCLKOutput_Disable;
    I2S_Init(SPI2, &i2s);
    I2S_Cmd(SPI2, ENABLE);
}    

void mp45dt02_start(void){
    SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI2, SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
}

void SPI2_IRQHandler(void){
    if(SPI_GetITStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE)){
        uint16_t sample=SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI2);
        mic_in_buf[mic_buf_index++]=HTONS(sample);
        if(mic_buf_index == MIC_IN_BUF_SIZE){
            mic_buf_index=0;
            PDM_Filter_64_LSB((uint8_t *)mic_in_buf, mic_out_buf, 40, &pdm_filter);
            uint32_t i;
            for(i=0; i<MIC_OUT_BUF_SIZE; i++){
                enqueve(mic_out_buf[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the DAC:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_spi.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_i2c.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "cs43l22.h"
#include "queve.h"

#define FS 16000
#define CS43L22_I2C I2C1
#define CS43L22_I2C_ADDR 0x94

void cs43l22_init(void){
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;

    NVIC_InitTypeDef nvic;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannel = SPI3_IRQn;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&nvic);

    //CS43L22 /RESET(PD4)
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_4;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpio);

    //CS43L22 I2C SDA(PB9) in SCL(PB6)
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_9;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_OD;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

    //CS43L22 I2S3 WS(PA4);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_4;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_SPI3);

    //CS43L22 I2S3 MCK(PC7), SCK(PC10), SD(PC12)
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_12;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_SPI3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_SPI3);

    //I2S config
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI3, ENABLE);
    SPI_DeInit(SPI3);
    I2S_InitTypeDef i2s;
    i2s.I2S_AudioFreq=FS;
    i2s.I2S_MCLKOutput=I2S_MCLKOutput_Enable;
    i2s.I2S_Mode=I2S_Mode_MasterTx;
    i2s.I2S_DataFormat=I2S_DataFormat_16b;
    i2s.I2S_Standard=I2S_Standard_Phillips;
    i2s.I2S_CPOL=I2S_CPOL_Low;
    I2S_Init(SPI3, &i2s);
    I2S_Cmd(SPI3, ENABLE);

    //I2C1 config
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
    I2C_InitTypeDef i2c;
    i2c.I2C_ClockSpeed=100000;
    i2c.I2C_Mode=I2C_Mode_I2C;
    i2c.I2C_Ack=I2C_Ack_Enable;
    i2c.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress=I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
    i2c.I2C_DutyCycle=I2C_DutyCycle_2;
    i2c.I2C_OwnAddress1=99;
    I2C_Init(I2C1, &i2c);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

    //CS43L22 config
    //Recommended Power-up sequence (page 31)

    //bring reset high
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_4);

    //wait
    volatile uint32_t j;
    for(j=0; j<20000000; j++);

    //Required initialization settings (page 32)
    uint8_t reg;
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x0, 0x99);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x47, 0x80);
    reg=cs43l22_read_reg(0x32);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x32, reg | 0x80);
    reg=cs43l22_read_reg(0x32);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x32, reg & 0x7F);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x0, 0x00);

    cs43l22_write_reg(0x02, 0x01);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x04, 0xAF);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x05, 0x80);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x06, 0x07);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x02, 0x9E);

    cs43l22_write_reg(0x0A, 0x00);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x0E, 0x04);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x27, 0x00);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x1F, 0x0F);

    cs43l22_write_reg(0x1A, 0x7F);
    cs43l22_write_reg(0x1B, 0x7F);
}

void cs43l22_start(void){
    SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI3, SPI_I2S_IT_TXE, ENABLE);
}

void cs43l22_write_reg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data){
    i2c_write(CS43L22_I2C, CS43L22_I2C_ADDR, reg, data);
}

uint8_t cs43l22_read_reg(uint8_t reg){
    return i2c_read(CS43L22_I2C, CS43L22_I2C_ADDR, reg);
}

void cs43l22_write_sound_data(uint16_t data_l, uint16_t data_r){
    while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE));
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, data_l);
    while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE));
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, data_r);
}

static uint8_t lr;
static uint16_t data;

void SPI3_IRQHandler(void){
    if(SPI_GetITStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_IT_TXE)){
        if(lr == 0){
            if(queve_empty()){
                SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, 0);
            }
            else{
                data=dequeve();
                //left channel
                SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, data);
                lr=1;
    }
        }
        else{
            //right channel
            SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, data);
            lr=0;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is main:

```
cs43l22_init();
mp45dt02_init();

mp45dt02_start();

//fill queve a little
volatile uint32_t j;
for(j=0; j<10000000; j++);

while(1){
    while(queve_empty());
    audio=dequeve();
    cs43l22_write_sound_data(audio, audio);
}
```

Edit:
My other observations:

- when I debugged with leds, I noticed that after some time queve gets empty, no matter how much delay I use at beginning (this only happens at sampling rate higher than 16kHz)-> so maybe the problem is in clocks, unfortunately I have no equipment to check this

[This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13583550/stack_exchange/mic_bin_stack.rar) is link to zip file. Inside are compiled examples that I mentioned above. I think that filenames are self-explainatory. If someone is interested and have discovery board it would be great to flash programs and see about what problem I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that platform but I wonder if calling the PDM filter within the interrupt is a good idea. Do you have enough RAM to be able to double-buffer the captured samples so that can occur outside the interrupt?

Comment: I had the same doubt so I tried version without any interrupts (as I mentioned in my post) - to see if maybe that's the problem, but there is no difference.

Comment: What is the "queve.h" that you include?

Comment: What have you done to verify that your clock frequency is, in fact, 168 MHz??

Comment: @ScottSeidman I generated system_stm32f4xx.c using STM's excel app where clock frequency can be set. UART's and timers are working as expected so I assume frequency is trully 168 MHz (or any other which I want).

Comment: @kahyas queve.c is my implementation of queve. It is not used at non-interrupt example but problem still persist.

Comment: I had the same problem with you. At last you mention that maybe the problem is in closks. But I don't think so. Because I had checked it(BCLK: for mp45dt02, it acturally is 3.072MHz at 48kHz.).

Comment: What is a queve ? a queue ? FIFO? LIFO?

Comment: @Blup1980 it's fifo

Comment: There is another mistake in your interrupt handler: interrupt flag is not cleared. That may causes this issue.